# Bluer than that of [X] or ...than [X's]

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Are both of these sentence correct? If so which is preferable or most clear? Thank you.

(1)The color of Lake Superior is bluer than that of Lake Huron.
Or
(2)The color of Lake Superior is bluer than Lake Huron's.

Comment: Try "Lake Superior is bluer than Lake Huron." We all know that blue is a color, it's a waste of words to explain it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. This is because both are using the genitive case(describing possession). Both are describing the color of lakes, expressed in that of the first instance, and the second However, The second is simpler to comprehend, as it compresses the noun into one genitive word, and is not difficult to comprehend. Therefore, you should use the second one.

Comment: @Victor if you found my answer to correctly solve your question, please don't forget to mark the question as solved.